# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic' for NAV SOAP client in Dot Net core 3.1 upgrade

Tags: .net-core, soap-client, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.2, dynamics-nav

I have dot net core 2.2 application which consuming NAV SOAP endpoint working fine in the IIS environment.
I have upgraded to dot net core 3.1 where the SOAP endpoint not working giving the error "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'."

While debugging I come to know Channel, Inner channel and State is not initialize properly in dot net 3.1 generally state should be open but it's showing faulted.

Exception -- system.servicemodel.communicationobjectfaultedexception.

Please find below snapshot for more information.
[Proxy class initialization sanpshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq7Aj.png)

Comment: What authentication are you using?

Comment: It's Basic..........
result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

Comment: I’m pretty sure Nav doesn’t support basic. It is only NTLM or Kerberos. In your case it is Negotiate, that means Kerberos. It shouldn’t depend on dotnet version you are using.

Comment: I tried with NTLM.....
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'.

Comment: Because Negotiate means Kerberos. If you want to use NTLM you need to reconfigure Nav/BC server instance to use NTLM. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/configure-server-instance you need `Use NTLM Authentication` flag set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved.

This issue because of an improper upgrade to Dot Net core 3.1.
and System.ServiceModel should have Version="4.4.4"